# Derivative of $F(X)G(X)$

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,$F(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,$G(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.Does the following expression holds:$\frac{\partial F(X)G(X)}{\partial X}$=$\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial X}$$(G(X) \otimes I)$+$\frac{\partial G(X)}{\partial X}(I \otimes F(X))$? I have already known there exists such an expression $\frac{\partial F(X)G(X)}{\partial (\vec X)^T}$=$(G(X)^T \otimes I)$$\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial (\vec X)^T}$+$(I \otimes F(X))\frac{\partial G(X)}{\partial (\vec X)^T}$(Ref: https://www.janmagnus.nl/papers/JRM012.pdf theorem 9).Are they equivalent?Also what are the differences between $\frac{\partial}{\partial (\vec X)^T}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial (\overrightarrow{ X^T})}$

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial (\vec X)^T}F
  = (\frac{\partial}{\partial (\vec X)}F)^T
$

Comment: I see.So the correct expression should be ...+$\frac{\partial G(X)}{\partial X}(I \otimes (F(X))^T)$

Comment: I mean,the second expression is correct.I modified the first expression

Comment: Yeah correct...

Comment: $
\def\grad#1#2{\left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right)}
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
$Those expressions don't look right, but if you define
$$H = FG,\quad f=\v(F),\quad g=\v(G),\quad h=\v(H),\quad x=\v(X)$$
then you can say either of the following
$$\eqalign{
&\grad H{X_{ij}}=\grad F{X_{ij}}G+F\grad G{X_{ij}}\\
&\grad hx=\left(G^T\otimes I\right)\grad fx+\left(I\otimes F\right)\grad gx
}$$ The true gradient $\grad HX$ is a fourth-order tensor.

Comment: However,for the latter expression you gave(the derivative of vec),there is a transpose operator on vec (X) in the reference https://www.janmagnus.nl/papers/JRM012.pdf  so which is correct?